# How to update details of farmer in spring boot through the UserServiceImpl class?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, backend

How to update details of farmer through the userServiceImpl class? We cant use the farmerServiceImpl as we have to pass the username as the input not the id and username is not present in farmerClass.

User class:

```
public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory")
        @Size(max = 20)
        private String username;
        @NotBlank(message = "Password is mandatory")
        @Size(max = 50)
        private String password;
        
        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
        private Set<Role> roles;
        
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade =  {CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.PERSIST},
                mappedBy = "user")
        @JsonIgnore
        private Farmer farmer;
    }
```

Farmer Class:

```
public class Farmer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int farmerId;
    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String name;    
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 120)
    private String address;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 12)
    private String phoneNo;

    // OneToOne unidirectional relationship 
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;
    

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java  :

```
@Override
    public User updateUser(String username, User user) {
<<<How to update details of farmer class through this method>>>
    return userRepository.save(userDetails);
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Can you explain me how to pass the updated inputs through the userDetails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches for this , you can use  farmerServiceImpl too for that you will have to use SQL query with join like below

```
@Qyery(value="select f.* from farmer f join user u on f.farmerid=u.id where u.username=:username", native query=true)
Optional<Farmer> getFarmerByUsername(@Param("username") String username)
```

You can use the above query to retrieve the farmer who has username as provided like below

```
public User updateUser(String username, Farmer farmer) {
    Farmer  farmer=farmerRepository.getFarmerByUsername("username");
    farmer.setName("some name");
    farmer.setAddress("address");
    farmer.setPhoneNo("9999999999");
    //Then just save the farmer object
    farmerRepository.save(farmer); 
          
      }
```

The other approach is by using userRepository as below:

```
public User updateUser(String username, Farmer farmer) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

Farmer farmer=user.getFarmer();
farmer.setName("some name");
    farmer.setAddress("address");
    farmer.setPhoneNo("9999999999");
    //Then just save the farmer object
    farmerRepository.save(farmer);
}
```

Comment: I used the 2nd approach and it is working fine. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

1. Retrieve the User by passing the username as argument.
2. Then you can make any changes to the farmer class since it is also a member of the User class.
3. Save the user class, since you are using cascade type persist any changes made to the farmer will be saved in the farmer table as well.

Your method will look something like this:

```
public User updateUser(String username, Farmer farmer) {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    //If you want to update only a particular field of the Farmer class
    user.getFarmer().setName("someName");

    //Or if you are receiving a farmer object as method parameter then you can use something like this
    Integer id = user.getFarmer().getFarmerId();
    user.setFarmer(farmer);
    user.getFarmer().setFarmerId(id);

    //save the user class
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: This approach is removing the foreign key from the farmer table. Btw thanks for the help!